# Php can't get foreign key object id

Tags: php

i'm trying to get foreign key object id but it's not working.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT a.*, q.* FROM answer a inner join question q on a.question_id = q.id WHERE a.question_id = 1";

$result2 = $conn ->query($sql2);

while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<input name='group1' type='radio' id='". $row2['id'] ."' />" . "<label for='". $row2['id'] ."'>".$row2['answer_text']."</label>";
}
```

Comment: Does it not return an error?

Comment: no it works on answer_text but id value is always 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result2 = $conn ->query($sql2);
```

There have no space after `$conn`

Try it without space:

```
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
```

Comment: if you want to select all answer associated with question try this code:

`"SELECT a.*, q.* FROM answer AS a INNER JOIN question AS q ON a.question_id = q.id"`

Comment: still same $row['id'] is always 1

Comment: if you need individual question wise answer you pass the dynamic id using SUPER GLOBAL varibale `$_GET`
Like This:

`WHERE a.question_id = $_GET['id']`

Comment: it works on question it displays all of them but somehow on id field it doesn't work, i need this id field in order to produce different id for radiobuttons

Comment: Try this:

`"SELECT a.id as answer_id, a.*, q.id as question_id, q.* FROM answer a inner join question q on a.question_id = q.id WHERE a.question_id = 1"`;

`while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<input name='group1' type='radio' id='". $row2['answer_id'] ."' />" . "<label for='". $row2['question_id'] ."'>".$row2['answer_text']."</label>";
}`